# How to create a Dictionary out of two separate lists using linq and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq

I am practicing Linq and Lambda Expressions. I have two classes like these :

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsPaid { get; set; }
    public Invoice()
    {

    }
    public Invoice(int invoiceId, int employeeId, DateTime invoiceDate, DateTime dueDate, bool? isPaid)
    {
        InvoiceId = invoiceId;
        EmployeeId = employeeId;
        InvoiceDate = invoiceDate;
        DueDate = dueDate;
        IsPaid = isPaid;
    }
}
```

and :

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeType { get; set; }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int id, DateTime birthDate, string department, double rating, int employeeType)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        ID = id;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
        Department = department;
        Rating = rating;
        EmployeeType = employeeType;
    }
    public Person()
    {

    }
}
```

and I have two Lists :

```
List<Person> employee = new List<Person> {//some instances of Person here}
```

and

```
List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice> {//some instances of invoice here}
```

as you see, EmployeeId in Invoice class refers to ID of Person. I want to create a Dictionary Like this:

```
var myDictionary=new Dictionary<"employeeName", List<employeeInvoices> >
```

is that possible with linq and lambda expressions?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
    Dictionary<string, List<Invoice>> result = employee.ToDictionary(e => string.Format("{0} {1}", e.FirstName, e.LastName),
        e => invoices.Where(i => i.EmployeeId == e.ID).ToList());
```

Here is full code:

```
        var employee = new List<Person>() {
            new Person("FN", "LN", 1, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1), "", 1.1, 1),
            new Person("FN1", "LN1", 2, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1), "", 1.1, 1)
        };

        var invoices = new List<Invoice>() {
            new Invoice(1, 1, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, false),
            new Invoice(2, 2, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, false),
            new Invoice(3, 1, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, false),
        };

        Dictionary<string, List<Invoice>> result =
            employee.ToDictionary(e => string.Format("{0} {1}", e.FirstName, e.LastName),
                e => invoices.Where(i => i.EmployeeId == e.ID).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You want to transform the list of employees to a dictionary, where the key will be the employee, and the value will be the list of invoices for which `EmployeeId` is equal to the employee's `ID`.

Translating the above paragraph to LINQ gives us

```
var myDictionary = employees.ToDictionary(
                        emp => emp, 
                        emp => invoices.Where(inv => inv.EmployeeId == emp.ID).ToList());
```

What I'm trying to point out here, is that LINQ can easily be translated to plain English and understood by anybody. Translation from English to LINQ is usually possible to too - you just have to rephrase your problem using the words (methods) available in LINQ.